# ros2 concatenate string to launchargument

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am trying to port an old melodic project to eloquent and was wondering on how to concatenate strings to an launch argument like so:

```
return LaunchDescription([
    DeclareLaunchArgument('id', default_value='75', description="an id"),
    DeclareLaunchArgument('target', default_value="robot_"+launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('id')+"/target"),
    Node(
        package='wand_control',
        node_executable='wand_control',
        output='screen',
        node_name="wand_control",
        node_namespace="aq_"+launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("id"),
        parameters=[{
            "target" : launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('target')
        }]
    )
])
```

but there is an error on the line where I am trying to set the launch argument 'target':

```
must be str, not LaunchConfiguration
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358655/ros2-concatenate-string-to-launchargument/) by [.zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/40609/.zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2020-08-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can replace the string concatenation with an array, e.g.:

```
import launch
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, LogInfo
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration


def generate_launch_description():
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('id', default_value='75', description='an id'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('target', default_value=['robot_', LaunchConfiguration('id'), '/target']),
        LogInfo(msg=LaunchConfiguration('target'))
    ])
```

---

Originally posted by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) with karma: 486 on 2020-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [.zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/40609/.zero/) on 2020-08-06**:
Thank you!
But why does it work that way?

**Comment by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) on 2020-08-08**:
Maybe somebody with a better understanding may be more suitable for this question.

But, the `default_value` parameter is an array (
https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d8b12df2a6bbb307f845f06f00245e74b58041ef/launch/launch/actions/declare_launch_argument.py#L81) and each element in the array is resolved as a substitution (
https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d8b12df2a6bbb307f845f06f00245e74b58041ef/launch/launch/actions/declare_launch_argument.py#L91). Therefore, it shows that the `DeclareLaunchArgument` accepts a list of substitutions (or strings that are converted to substitutions).

Very often, substitutions accept a list, like `PathJoinSubstitution` (
https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d8b12df2a6bbb307f845f06f00245e74b58041ef/launch/launch/substitutions/path_join_substitution.py#L29) and later it gets concatenated (https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d8b12df2a6bbb307f845f06f00245e74b58041ef/launch/launch/substitutions/path_join_substitution.py#L46)